# Como "reimportar" um objeto de um módulo de Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, importação, import

Escrevi um módulo chamado `mymodule.py` que possui a função

```
def funcion(x):
     return x
```

Então, importei essa função em um código como

```
from mymodule import function
```

e funcionou normalmente.

Depois quis mudar a função para

```
def function(x):
     return 2*x
```

mas o código continua funcionando como na versão anterior do `function`, com `return x`. Como faço para reimportar o objeto `function`sem precisar reiniciar o kernel? Vocês conhecem alguma função parecida com o `importlib.reload()` para objetos em Python 3?

Comment: O que seria "reiniciar o kernel" nesse contexto? Você precisa alterar a aplicação com ela rodando?

Comment: Anderrson, eu uso o Jupyter Notebook. Nele, para eu reimportar algum modulo preciso reiniciar o Kernel, então quero fazer essa reimportação sem precisar reiniciá-lo, com ele rodando.

Answer (score 2):

Antes da possível solução, é bom saber:
O processo de reload não é livre de falhas pois se é certo que o as variáveis são atualizadas, não é garantido que as antigas são removidas, por exemplo, se voce renomeia alguma, o nome antigo pode continuar existindo, se voce muda tipos de objetos nas definições de classes, objetos existentes podem continuar com seus tipos antigos.* Então cuidado com o reload, embora as vezes seja bem conveniente.

[Versão 3.0 até a 3.3:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload)

```
imp.reload(module)
```

[Versão 3.4+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)

```
importlib.reload(module)
```

* como constatei isso? utilizando muuito o jupyter notebook e verificando várias falhas no processo de reload, depois de alguma pesquisa vi que não estava sozinho. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando o **jupyter**, basta pressionar «Shift»+«Enter» na célula, você verá que o número dela ente colchetes aumentará, isto significa que a função foi "relida" e que agora está disponível com a nova sintaxe (o mesmo vale para definições de variáveis ou qualquer trecho de código dentro de uma célula).